# Javascript - iterating thru object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
   const module = {
      video: [
         { id: 1, title: 'video', component: <Video />},
      ],
      condensed: [
         { id: 2, title: 'condensed', component: <Condensed /> },
      ],
      full: [
         { id: 3, title: 'full', component: <Full /> },
      ],
   };
```

Is there a way to loop through an object array in which the arrays are named? Hopefully I'm using the correct language to describe this.
I'm looking to print out id and title for each array.

If the data looks like this, I believe I can use a for loop (but I realize that I can use forEach or map):

```js
const module = {
      video: [
         { id: 1, title: 'video', component: <Video />},
         { id: 2, title: 'condensed', component: <Condensed /> },
      ],

for (var key in module.video) {
    var obj = module.video[key];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about the array being in an object. Just use `module.video` like any other variable that holds an array.

Comment: are those strings inside the `component` key?

Comment: Doesn't key in this case represent each of the objects within video? Wouldn't `obj.id` and `obj.title` work?

Comment: Please either mark the answer that best answered your question or specify what is missing from the answers so that we can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` will be simplest for your use case

```js
const module = {
  video: [
    { id: 1, title: "video" },
    { id: 2, title: "condensed" },
  ],
};

// option 1
module.video.forEach(({ id, title }) => {
  console.log(id, title);
});


// option 2
for (var key in module.video) {
  const { id, title } = module.video[key];
  console.log(id, title);
}

// option 3
for (const item of module.video) {
  const { id, title } = item;
  console.log(id, title);
}
```

If need to traverse the main object and inside arrays

```js
const module = {
  video: [{ id: 1, title: "video", component: "" }],
  condensed: [{ id: 2, title: "condensed", component: "<Condensed />" }],
  full: [{ id: 3, title: "full", component: "<Full />" }],
};

Object.entries(module).forEach(([key, items]) => {
  console.log("-->", key);
  items.forEach(({ id, title }) => {
    console.log(id, title);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think that what the OP wants is to loop thru every array within titles, 1st `video`, 2nd `condensed` and then `Full`

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to iterate through the module object you can simply use for...in

```
for (var el in module) {
        // Whatever you want to do
    }
```

Where you will need to use module[el] to get the whole objects.
If you want a way to iterate though all children of children you can simply use a for...in with a foreach inside

```
for (var el in module) {
        module[el].forEach((element) => {
            // Whatever you want to do
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for-in` with `Array#each` as follows:

```js
const module = { video: [ { id: 1, title: 'video', component: '<Video />'}, ], condensed: [ { id: 2, title: 'condensed', component: '<Condensed />' }, ], full: [ { id: 3, title: 'full', component: '<Full />' }, ], };

for( const key in module ) {
    module[key].forEach(
        ({id,title}) => console.log( id, title )
    );
}
```

**Alternatively ......**

You can use `for-of` with `Object.values` and `Array#forEach` as follows:

```js
const module = { video: [ { id: 1, title: 'video', component: '<Video />'}, ], condensed: [ { id: 2, title: 'condensed', component: '<Condensed />' }, ], full: [ { id: 3, title: 'full', component: '<Full />' }, ], };

for( const value of Object.values(module) ) {
    value.forEach(
        ({id,title}) => console.log( id, title )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that by getting the object keys with the help of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method and then iterating these keys values with the help of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to get the `id` and `title` property values.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const module = {
  video: [
    { id: 1, title: 'video', component: '<Video />'},
  ],
  condensed: [
    { id: 2, title: 'condensed', component: '<Condensed />' },
  ],
  full: [
    { id: 3, title: 'full', component: '<Full />' },
  ]
};

Object.keys(module).forEach(key => {
    module[key].forEach(obj => {
    console.log('ID : ', obj.id);
    console.log('Title : ', obj.title);
  })
});
```